# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {})/If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. Help me?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I'm using storyBook with react.tsx and I get this error from the title. I tried to look what was wrong but without any success. Here is my 3 scripts

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Button.css";

export interface IButtonProps {
  variant: "primary" | "secondary" | "success" | "danger";
  title: string;
}

const Button: React.FC<IButtonProps> = (variant, title) => {
  return <button className={`button ${variant}`}>{title}</button>;
};

export default Button;
```

I will not add CSS...

```js
import React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";
import { Meta } from "@storybook/react";

export default {
  title: "Button",
  component: Button,
} as Meta;

export const Primary: React.VFC<{}> = () => (
  <Button variant="primary" title="Primary"></Button>
);
export const Secondary: React.VFC<{}> = () => (
  <Button variant="secondary" title="Secondary">
    Secondary
  </Button>
);
export const Success: React.VFC<{}> = () => (
  <Button variant="success" title="Success">
    Success
  </Button>
);
export const Danger: React.VFC<{}> = () => (
  <Button variant="danger" title="Primary">
    Danger
  </Button>
);
```

And when I try to run it I get this : [enter link description here](https://prnt.sc/1uv8ps2)

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in your parameters in `Button` Functional Component. You pass two parameters in the parentheses `variant, title`. However when you define the Props Object you should pass only one parameter, namely the props (it doesn't matter how you name it, I always call it props for clarity). So like this:

```
const Button: React.FC<IButtonProps> = (props) => {
    return <button className={`button ${props.variant}`}>{props.title}</button>;
};
```

This way React loads the passed props in the predefined object and which is you param. Therefore you need to call each attribute of props in your return. The error shows up because `variant` ends up being the props object (props are passed to the first param), while `title` ends up being an empty object. When you pass the object as the button title, the app throws the error because it expects string not an empty object. You can check it by yourself when you `console.log(vairant, title)` before you return the button.